# List files that don't have certain letters in the first two character

Tags: bash, grep

I need to list filenames that are at least two characters long and don't have the following letters in the first two characters. The letters are abcfghxyz

So far I have:

```
ls | grep -v '^[abcfghxyz]'
```

This is checking to see if the file does not contain one of those letter at the beginning.

But how do I check for the first two characters and file that is at least two character long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't even need `grep` for this:

```
ls -1d [^abcfghxyz][^abcfghxyz]*
```

This uses `ls`'s `-1` option to get one filename per line rather than columnar output, and the `-d` option to stop `ls` from listing the contents of any subdirectores that match the glob.

Another alternative is to use `find` (so that you can explicitly limit the output to regular files and not directories or symlinks etc):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '[^abcfghxyz][^abcfghxyz]*'
```

Comment: actually, that doesn't work correctly.  This will exclude a file called `foo`, while the `grep -v` version doesn't - which seems a better match for what the OP asked for.  i'll leave my answer here rather than delete it as an example of a not-quite-right approach, and explanation of why it's not right.

Comment: it worked for me

Comment: actually, cas, I might have misunderstood the requirement. If *both* of the first two letters have to not match, then yours is the right answer.  mine will let through files that fail exactly one of the [bracket] tests, such as "foo", which fails the "don't have the following letters in the first two characters" requirement.

Comment: @shawnedward - so which is the right interpretation?  maybe accept the answer that best matches what you wanted.  or add more info to your Question if neither is right.

Comment: what I need was your command, so I guess your answer is right but Jeff answer is great as well

Comment: if piped `ls` is always sending one file per line, no need to add "-1"  parameter.

Comment: my `ls` command above is not piping its output to anywhere, so `-1` is required.  also, `-1` is harmless if the output is being piped - has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

```
ls | grep .. | grep -v '^[abcfghxyz][abcfghxyz]'
```

Comment: As an alternative : `ls | egrep -v '^[abcfghxyz]{2}'`

Comment: how do I implement that it the name has to be at least two characters long

Comment: the [bracketed] sections each require one character, so having two bracketed sections means you have to have at least two characters.

Comment: thanks for the nudge, shawn - `grep -v` allows "nothing" to not match [abcfghxyz], so I added a `grep ..` to require two characters in the filename

Comment: The fact that the option '-v' is a negation of the pattern means that what you present negates all files with 2 characters. A file with one letter also match that rule. The solution proposed by cas works correctly.

Comment: good point, BinaryZebra; I added the `grep ..` to catch the single-letter files, but I'm now realizing that cas's answer is the correct interpretation of the requirement (IMHO). mine only excludes files that fail *both* [bracketed] requirements, allowing files like "foo" when it should not.